# Vim does not let me :q (quit)

Tags: vim

I have `MiniBuffer` plugin installed within my `VIM` (might be helpful, I guess). The problem with it is that it don't let me :q (quit). Once I go to normal mode, enter :q, window just blinks and does nothing, so I can't even close file. What may be wrong?

Comment: perhaps a :q! would work?

Comment: nope :) It's kinda strange behavior. I used `VIM` for 4 months but never encountered such problem. After  followed [this guide](http://sontek.net/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide) I could not quit with `:q` with 2+ buffers open

Comment: does `:qall!` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did `:bufdo quit` and got `vim` to quit session. Probably, it might be the answer.

Just to complete the answer. via @Yab :qall (and :qall!) solves problem.

Comment: `:qa` and `:qa!` are the short forms.